# ANGULARJS -validate on submit only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I would like to do a validation on submit only. Right now, I've created a directive for an input that checks if minimum value is 5000 but I dont want it to check each number I type via keypress. I only want it to check when I hit submit. 
Here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/58b7491d/

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myAppApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitPlanInfo(myForm.$valid);">
            <div>
                <label for="initInvestment">Number (Min: 5000)</label>
                <input id="initInvestment" name="initInvestment" class="form-control" ng-model="model1.InitInvestment" required min-Value="5000"/>
                <p ng-show="myForm.initInvestment.$invalid && myForm.initInvestment.$dirty && myForm.$submitted" class="validation">Min Value should be 5000</p>

            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
angular.module('myAppApp', [])
.directive('minValue', function () {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$validators.minValueErrMsg = function (value) {
                var status = true;
                console.log(value);
                if (value < attrs.minValue) {
                    status = false;
                }
                return status;
            };
        }
    };
})
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $controller) {
    //LETS DO THE FORM VALIDATION AFTER HITTING SUBMIT!!
    $scope.submitPlanInfo = function (isValid) {
        console.log($scope.myForm);
        if ($scope.myForm.$valid) {
            console.log($scope.myForm.initInvestment);
           // console.log(angular.isNumber(parseInt($scope.myForm.initInvestment.$modelValue)));
            var minVal = parseInt($scope.myForm.initInvestment.$modelValue);
           // console.log(angular.isNumber(minVal));
            if (minVal < 5000){
                console.log("should be min 5000");
                return false;
            }else{
                console.log("success");
                return true;
            }
            alert("Valid");
        }

    };
    //END OF FORM VALIDATION
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO validating after submit is not a very good UX.  I would try using `ng-messages` directive along with setting `ng-model-options` to update on `blur`.

[Consider reading year of moo's post about this](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html)

He goes into some depth about validators, both synchronous and asynchronous, along with a little section on `ng-model-options`.

[Angular docs - ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions)

[Angular docs - ngMessages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages)

Comment: I ended up using this method. Thanks Cory